# sopaui test - extract response value and use it in a flat text

Tags: json, automated-tests, soapui

I've a JSON response like this:

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "key":"123145"
}
```

I need to use the value of "key" as input for a payload request:

```
param=1&param=2&param3=$key
```

I would like to write the request like :

```
param=1&param=2&param3=${keyValue}
```

so the result should be

```
param=1&param=2&param3=12345
```

I've tried with Property Transfer but doesn't works.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a property transfer test step like this:

[image]

Here you're transferring a value to a test-case level property called `myProperty` (which you created previously). Then, you can reference this property in your URL as `${#TestCase#myProperty}`

Comment: Hi there, which kind of SOAPUI version are you using? I'm using SOAPUI 5.4.0 for mac, and I don't have this kind of settings in my Property Transfer window...

Comment: I did the original in soapUI for Windows. I've reproduced it above on my Mac version of soapUI.

Answer (score 1):

So you can proceed like below

1) Fetch value you want from json using groovy step

2) Store the fetched value from Groovy Step into TestCase Property

3) Use that value in the request you want

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def input=context.expand('${SampleRequest#Request}')
log.info input

def jsonObj=new JsonSlurper().parseText(input)

def key=jsonObj.key
log.info key
```

testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("Key",key)

[image]

The value stored can be used as below in a request. Syntax to access Property Value

```
${#TestCase#Key}
```

[image]

Comment: are you fetching the request.. but I should read the value from response

Comment: Actually my request was not fetching response. So for demo purpose i wrote request. you can change it to RawRequest or Response as per requirement